# Catalin Seo price slider not working on mobile (magento)

Tags: magento

I have an issue with https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/layered-navigation-seo.html . Price slider not working on mobile devices. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file app/design/frontend/{your-theme}/default/template/catalin_seo/catalog/layer/price.phtml

Replace

```
    CatalinSeoHandler.bindPriceSlider();
```

With

```
    var bindPriceSliderStop = false;
    if(window.innerWidth < 770) {
        jQuery('body').on('click', '.block-layered-nav .block-content.accordion-open > dl > dt.current', function(){
            if(jQuery('.current .price-slider').length && !bindPriceSliderStop){
                CatalinSeoHandler.bindPriceSlider();
                bindPriceSliderStop = true;
            }   
        });
    }else{
        CatalinSeoHandler.bindPriceSlider();
    }

    jQuery(window).on("orientationchange",function(event){
        if(window.innerWidth > 770) {
            catalinSeoHandlerMobile();              
        }else{
            jQuery('body').on('click', '.block-layered-nav .block-content.accordion-open > dl > dt.current', function(){
                if(jQuery('.current .price-slider').length){
                    catalinSeoHandlerMobile();
                }   
            });
            if(jQuery('.current .price-slider').length){
                catalinSeoHandlerMobile();
            }
        }
    });

    function catalinSeoHandlerMobile(){
        CatalinSeoHandler.priceSlider.currentMinPrice = parseFloat(jQuery('#price-min-display').text());
        CatalinSeoHandler.priceSlider.currentMaxPrice = parseFloat(jQuery('#price-max-display').text());
        CatalinSeoHandler.bindPriceSlider();
    }
```

There is another problem, price slider does not support **mobile touch event**. If you wanna solve this problem, replace standard magento slider js file

> "js/scriptaculous/slider.js"

With this

> http://dev.amnuts.com/slider/js/slider.js